# How to create multidimensional array from query?

Tags: php, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I have 2 tables:

```
category(id_cat,cat_name)  
sub_cat(id_cat,id_sub_cat,sub_cat_name)
```

I want to create a view by joining these tables. I have created a controller with code like this:

```
$d['category'] = $this->db->query('select * from category a left join sub_cat b on a.id_cat=b.id_cat');
$this->load->view('cat',$d);
```

and my view :

```
<table><tr><th>Cat Name</th><th>Sub Cat Name</th></tr> 
<?php foreach($category->result_array() as $dt) { ?>
<tr><td><?php echo $dt['cat_name'] ?></td><td><?php echo $dt['sub_cat_name']?></td></tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

and the result of my view is like this:

```
------------------------
cat_name | sub_cat_name 
------------------------
cat1     | sub 1
cat1     | sub 2
cat1     | sub 3
------------------------
cat2     | sub 1
cat2     | sub 2
------------------------
```

But I want the view to be something like this:

```
------------------------
cat_name | sub_cat_name 
------------------------
cat1     | sub 1
         | sub 2
         | sub 3
------------------------
cat 2    | sub 1
         | sub 2
------------------------
```

Comment: I rephrased the title to reduce [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and added some tags to improve visibility, then fixed formatting and grammar.

Comment: Can you please send your array format

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `temp` variable where you can store the `cat_name` and check if that `cat_name` is already used else it will not be echoed in your view:

```
<?php
    $temp = '';
    foreach($category->result_array() as $dt) {
        if ($dt['cat_name'] != $temp) {
            echo $dt['cat_name'];
            $temp = $dt['cat_name'];
        }
    }
?>
```

You can also put that into function so it will be messy in your view. Hope this helps. Note: It is suggested formatting of query must be done on a method (helper) file so you won't have a fat controller.

**Edit**

You can check the fiddle here: http://codepad.org/WwUm4zeZ

Comment: I've tried it, but the `cat_name` is not echoed at all.

Comment: I've edited the conditional statement from `equals (==)` to `not equals (!=)` please try it again. sorry my bad. I've tried it here is the link for my fiddle, http://codepad.org/WwUm4zeZ